# lightning:recordEditForm not working - create children on master-detail relatinship

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, create-records

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
<lightning:card title="Create Reservation">
    <lightning:recordEditForm
                              onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                              objectApiName="Campsite_Reservation__c">
        <!-- the messages component is for error messages -->
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Campsite__c" value="a041o00000ZWoFbAAL"/> 
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Reference__c"/>
        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
            <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" />
        </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</lightning:card>
```

```
({

    handleSuccess: function(cmp, event, helper) {
       var params = event.getParams();
       cmp.set('v.recordId', params.response.id);
    }
})
```

[image]

I'm setting the Id of the master record as the `value` on the new child record which should get created. When the save button is clicked, an error message is displayed as per the screenshot. Is this a known limitation?

Comment: check running user apex debug log. Is there an exception to update?

Comment: Just checked. No debug log is generated for this action.

Comment: I recently hit the same problem (and some others) - see [Anyone got a lightning:inputField working for a lookup?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207479/anyone-got-a-lightninginputfield-working-for-a-lookup).

Comment: I found that the "reparent" feature works, but the issue also re-occurs when the user edits a separate record and returns to the form to continue entering information. Thinking this is a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a weird issue even if in the logs the error message is not clear. The log just says REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING.

> {"message":"An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.","stackTrace":"","data":{"message":"An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.","statusCode":400,"enhancedErrorType":"RecordError","output":{"errors":[],"fieldErrors":{"Campsite__c":[{"constituentField":null,"duplicateRecordError":null,"errorCode":"REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING","field":"Campsite__c","fieldLabel":"Campsite","message":"Required fields are missing: [Campsite__c]"}]}}},"id":"-829756038"}"

There is a workaround available to solve this issue. You have to **set the *Reparentable Master Detail* to true** for Campsite__c and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Saroj. Yes, the workaround works. Ideally it will be good if Salesforce can sort the issue though!

Comment: Please mark it as Answer if this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround is just enable Child records can be reparented to other parent records after they are created in child object's master relation field.