# Are lightning:recordEditForm and lightning:inputField a bit buggy in Spring'18?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, bug, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

I'm trying to get my hands on lightning:recordEditForm and lightning:inputField

Im using it on Order Line Item like this

```
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!item.Id}" objectApiName="OrderItem" >
    <lightning:messages />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Quantity" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="UnitPrice" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="TotalPrice" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Description" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Now I'm experiencing the following bugs (or features):

- localization of numeric decimal separator is not supported: after focusing the edit, it falls into the English dot separator instead of the correct user-Local separator (e.g. "," the comma-character for Locale = German)
- Owner field Lookup(User,Queue) are not working correctly, because it's only working for Queues and not Users as Owner (Example Quote.Owner I can't pick or set Users)
- Standard Quantity-field is rendered with NO decimal places and step-size of the spinner is 1. This rounds the value to the next full integer and displays simply a wrong values
- Spinner step-size for currency fields is 0.01 which is pretty much useless

Comment: I had a bad time with [lookups](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207479/anyone-got-a-lightninginputfield-working-for-a-lookup).

Comment: where are you running this component? Is it in a custom .app, a tab or via app builder on a new page?

Comment: @StephenWoods it's running on a record flexipage (app builder). I've seen your deleted comment: "owner field lookups is a known limitation". Is there a list of known limitations? Haven't seen anything in the docs. Would be very helpful.

Comment: In Summer 18 also needs to be handled with consideration. Pls cf thread: https://twitter.com/ch_sz_knapp/status/1001155167956422658